# Flink: sum after window won't show result

Tags: scala, apache-flink

This is my original code, problem is that it won't print data

```
    withTimestampsAndWatermarks
      .map(line => (line._1,line._3))
      .keyBy(_._1)
      .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5L)))
//      .sum(1)
//      .print()
```

Then a test with reduce so I can see the process

```
      .reduce(new ReduceFunction[(String, Int)] {
        override def reduce(value1: (String, Int), value2: (String, Int)): (String, Int) = {
          println("----------reduce invoked-------" + s"${value1._2} + ${value2._2} ==> ${value1._2+value2._2}" )
          (value1._1,value1._2 + value2._2)
        }
      })
      .print()
```

My input

```
a,1000,1
a,2000,2
a,3000,3
a,5000,4
a,6000,5
a,9999,6
```

Output

```
----------reduce invoked-------1 + 2 ==> 3
----------reduce invoked-------3 + 3 ==> 6
----------reduce invoked-------4 + 5 ==> 9
----------reduce invoked-------9 + 6 ==> 15
```

Seems window's setting is correct, but it won't print result with sum()

Comment: The problem has something to do with the watermarks: the window isn't being triggered because a sufficiently large watermark isn't being produced. If you want help figuring out why, please share enough that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Base on your answer, I think it's the parallelism problem. I test with a small amount data, so the watermark won't generate enough. Thanks.